# Unable to pass the params[:fields] hash to controller method in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes, parameters

```
 routes.rb
-----------
resources :mail_settings
```

My form looks like this

```
the _form.html.erb
---------
<%= form_tag  '/mail_settings' do %>



<div class="fieldBlock">
 <%= label_tag :name %>  <%= text_field_tag :name%> </div>

<div class="fieldBlock">
 <%= label_tag :id%>  <%= text_field_tag :id%> </div>


<div class="actions fieldBlock">
 <%= submit_tag "Update Settings ", :class => "btn-large btn-success" %>
</div>


<% end %>
```

but I can access individual params like params[:name] without any problem, why is it not working when i try params[:mail_setting] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean why it is `params[:name]` and not `params[:mail_setting][:name]` ? If so, the reason is that you are using `form_tag` instead of just a `form`, and family of *_tag helpers [ i.e. text_field_tag ]. In that case you do not 'bind' form to the model - in general form_tag is much more flexible than form. However, You should be able to do something like

```
<%= text_field_tag "mail_setting[name]"%>
```

and you will get params[:mail_setting][:name]

Hope I guessed what you asked about!